# Text color not changing on hover

Tags: html, css

Quick CSS/HTML issue here, please excuse my lack of experience in the field.
I have a download button that I would like to change from having white text to having grey text on hover. Currently the text is white, however despite my defining of a :hover attribute to change the color, it remains white. Here's my code:

HTML:

`<a id="postLink" class="button2" href="#">Post</a>`

CSS:

```
.button2 {
display: inline-block;
width:163px;
color: #FFFFFF;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
padding: 12px 24px;
border: 1px solid #EFEFEF;
border-radius: 8px;
background: #589edb;
font: normal normal normal 20px raleway;
text-decoration: none;
z-index:150;
}
.button2 :hover{
 color:#555555;
}
.button2:focus {
    border: 1px solid #EFEFEF;
    background: #589edb;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#6abeff), to(#6abeff));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #589edb, #589edb);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #589edb, #589edb);
    text-decoration: none;
}
.button2:active {
    background: #589edb;
    color:#FFFFFF;

}
#postLink{
  color:#FFFFFF;

  &:hover{
    color:#55555;
}
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: you are missing and end bracket ?

Comment: It's there, I just forgot to include it. editted now.

Comment: I see 2 end brackets ..

Comment: #55555   is not a color...for the #postLink but you don't even need that. Just remove space in .button2: hover, and it works in a fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/qj85azbs/1/

Answer (score 0):

Your `.button2 :hover` should be `.button2:hover` the whitespace screws it up ;)

I would remove the

```
#postLink{
  color:#FFFFFF;

  &:hover{
    color:#55555;
}
}
```

as it adds nothing and might screw up your code. Are you using LessCSS or SASS? Otherwise, `&:hover` will not work. Then the `#postLink` will prioritise over the class and will keep it white.

Comment: I'm using sublime, which I believe ignores whitespace. Even still I removed the whitespace and the issue still stands. Thanks anyways!

Comment: Also, sublime does not ignore whitespaces as they are essential in coding. When using css selectors whitespacing (like a space) will cause it to look into the child elements, like so: `.parentClass .childClass`. Or the more obvious example: `.menu .menu-item`. The spacing between the classes is essential here.